# Error With Moving Conditional To Class

Tags: java, refactoring

I am working on a HW that involves implementing some refactoring techniques and I am running into an error that I just can't seem to spot.  I have the following method that was originally in the `Fish` class that I moved into a class called `Strategy`

```
public class Strategy
{
    public void move (Fish fish, Pond pond)
    {
        if (fish.getHunger() < 0.2)
        {
            if (fish.getSize() < 7.0)
            {
                double[] location = pond.findNearestPlant(fish.getX(), fish.getY());
                fish.swimTowards(location[0], location[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                double[] location = pond.findNearestSmallFish(fish.getX(), fish.getY());
                fish.swimTowards(location[0], location[1]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // There are more conditionals in this block.  I haven't done anything with them yet so I didn't put them in.
        }
    }
}
```

and I am trying to transform the conditionals in the `if` block into 2 separate classes that are also located in my `Strategy.java` file.

```
class SmallFish extends Strategy
{
    public void move (Fish fish, Pond pond)
    {
        double[] location = pond.findNearestPlant(fish.getX(), fish.getY());
        fish.swimTowards(location[0], location[1]);
    }
}

class BigFish extends Strategy
{
    public void move (Fish fish, Pond pond)
    {
        double[] location = pond.findNearestSmallFish(fish.getX(), fish.getY());
        fish.swimTowards(location[0], location[1]);
    }
}
```

Back in the `Fish` class I added a few lines of code to determine which class to call:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;

public class Fish
{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static int numberOfFish = 0;

    private double hunger;
    private double size;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private int id;

    // I added this line
    private Strategy strategy;

    private FishReport myFishReport = null;

    public Fish(double x, double y, FishReport report)
    {
        hunger = 0.9;
        size = 1.0;

        // Put it in the pond
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        id = numberOfFish;
        numberOfFish++;

        // I added this code
        if (hunger < 0.2 && size < 7.0)
            this.strategy = new SmallFish();
        else if (hunger < 0.2 && size >= 7.0)
            this.strategy = new BigFish();
        else
            this.strategy = new Strategy();

        myFishReport = report;
        if(myFishReport != null)
        {
            myFishReport.updateHunger(hunger);
            myFishReport.updateSize(size);
            myFishReport.updateLocation(x, y);
        }
    }

    public void age(double timePassed)
    {
        double deltaSize = size * (1 + hunger * Math.exp(-size * timePassed));
        size = size + deltaSize;

        hunger = hunger * Math.exp(-deltaSize/size);

        myFishReport.updateHunger(hunger);
        myFishReport.updateSize(size);   
    }

    public void move(Pond pond)
    {
        strategy.move(this, pond);
    }

    // More methods below that I did not touch.  Left out to keep code as short as possible.
}
```

My test suite still passed after I added the `SmallFish` class, but I had a failure after I added the `BigFish` class:

> JUnit Test Results:
>   testMoveStarving(FishTests): Starving fish should move expected:<10.2981> but was:<10.3965129880783>
>   Total number of tests: 8
>   Total number of failures: 1

Here is the test that fails:

```
public void testMoveStarving()
{
    // Create a new fish and report
    FishReport report = new FishReport();
    Fish fish = new Fish(10, 20, report);

    // Make a pond
    Pond pond = new Pond();

    // Grow the fish until starving
    fish.age(20);
    fish.age(20);
    fish.age(20);
    fish.age(20);

    // Move the fish, and check the new location
    fish.move(pond);

    // Check the new location
    assertEquals("Starving fish should move", 10.2981, report.getLocation()[0], 0.001);
    assertEquals("Starving fish should move", 20.5963, report.getLocation()[1], 0.001);
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that my conditional for the `BigFish` class in the `Fish` constructor is not accurate.  I've been staring at this for over an hour, so I think I just need another pair of eyes to point out where I am going wrong.  If there is something more extreme then just the conditional in the `Fish` constructor, please try to give hints as opposed to the answer.  Like I said, this is part of a HW assignment.

Thank you in advanced

**EDIT 1 -** I forgot to add the changed `move()` method in the `Fish` class.  It's fixed now.

**EDIT 2 -** Failing test has been posted. The test calls the `age()` method in the `Fish` class so I added that as well.

Comment: Can you post the failing test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what the rest of your code looks like, but if the `size` or `hunger` of the fish changes after construction, you will no longer be using the correct strategy. (As it stands, all your fish will be using the `Strategy` strategy, and neither `BigFish` nor `SmallFish`.)

It would probably make more sense to keep the strategy selection in the `move` method as opposed to the constructor.

Comment: Okay, I am still really new to these refactoring patterns so I am just following along with a similar example from some lecture slides.  The example has the conditionals in the constructor.

Comment: Which is perfectly fine as long as the underlying data that is used for the strategy selection is immutable.

Comment: Okay, so because the location of the fish is changing I should leave the conditionals in the `move()` function?

Comment: You're not using location to determine the strategy. Only `size` and `hunger`. If either of those changes, your strategy might need to be updated as well.

Comment: Okay, I actually just found something when I re-read the assignment write up: 

"After performing this, create a private method updateMoveStrategy in Fish, which sets / creates which strategy to use based on the hunger and size variables. This method should be called at the end of the age method in Fish. If done properly, all tests should still pass."

Which sounds exactly like what you were saying.